# Как найти нужный объект в массиве по клику на DOM элемент

Tags: javascript

Посылаю сигнал SOS)
В общем суть такая. Есть массив объектом, с 1 св-вом HTML. На основе которого строится html документ.

```
   const cardsArr = [
   {
      name: 'CJ',
      htmlCode: `<div class="card">
      <div class="card__inner">
         <div class="card__back "></div>
         <div class="card__front card--cj"></div>
      </div>
   </div> `,
   },
   {
      name: 'CJ',
      htmlCode: `<div class="card">
      <div class="card__inner">
         <div class="card__back "></div>
         <div class="card__front card--cj"></div>
      </div>
   </div> `,
   },
   {
      name: 'Big-Smoke',
      htmlCode: `<div class="card">
      <div class="card__inner">
         <div class="card__back "></div>
         <div class="card__front card--big-smoke"></div>
      </div>
   </div> `,
   },
   {
      name: 'Raider',
      htmlCode: `<div class="card">
      <div class="card__inner">
         <div class="card__back "></div>
         <div class="card__front card--raider"></div>
      </div>
   </div> `,
   },
   {
      name: 'Cop',
      htmlCode: `<div class="card">
      <div class="card__inner">
         <div class="card__back "></div>
         <div class="card__front card--cop"></div>
      </div>
   </div> `,
   },
]
```

А вот так вставляю в документ:

```
    cardsArr.forEach(el => {

   const containerEl = document.querySelector('.main__container');

   containerEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el.htmlCode);
})
```

ВОПРОС: Как мне связать DOM объект, который я строю с этим же объектом массива? Как мне отследить и найти по клику на DOM элемент и найти этот же объект в массиве? Я пытался сравнивать outerHTML и св-во объекта c html, но так почему-то не выходит и выдает false, хотя они одинаковы и тип Строка. Надеюсь вопрос понятен)

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом, чтобы желающим помочь было легче тестировать. Иначе им придётся набирать ваш код вручную или просто пройти мимо.

Comment: хорошо, так и буду делать) но тут неченго набирать тут все очевидно) но в след раз буду текстом

Comment: Ну вот мне, например, захотелось проверить, не меняется ли какая-то мелочь при переходах HTML>DOM>outerHTML, но я не могу. Могу поверить вам на слово, но ведь и вы можете что-то проглядеть.

Comment: а как она может меняться, если я этоже св-во вставляю в документ как html код, ничего не добавляя

Comment: "в след раз буду текстом" - Вам уже поставили три минуса.

Comment: Ну, например, браузер может при вставке HTML как-то оптимизировать пробелы, а может и нет — это только пример. Всегда лучше давать текст, даже если вам кажется, что всё очевидно.

Comment: исправил, извиняюсь

Comment: Ну вот тепер, например, видно, что у вас в конце каждого фрагмента HTML стоит пробел, который пропадёт при получении `outerHTML`. Или это опечатка только в коде вопроса?

Comment: Нет, Вы правы!) так и есть) как мне отметить как правильный ответ, или просто удалить вопрос? Спасибо за помощь, учту

Comment: Удалять не нужно, это тоже может быть хорошим опытом кому-то другому) Я предложил вам ещё один способ, если подходит, можно отметить его. Если нет, я заменю ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы ничего больше не вставляете в `'.main__container'`, можете получить индекс кликнутого элемента, а потом использовать его же в массиве карточек:

```js
const index = [...document.querySelectorAll('.main__container > div')]
                .indexOf(clickedElement);
const card = cardsArr[index];
```

Comment: это то, что я искал 2 дня) благодарю